# What is the proper way to integrate enum with administrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, administrate, rails-administrate

I have a rails app where the users have a gender, which is an enum, where 0 means female and 1 means male.

I have this code in the user_dashboard.rb:

```
require "administrate/base_dashboard"

class UserDashboard < Administrate::BaseDashboard
    ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
        posts: Field::HasMany,
        id: Field::Number.with_options(searchable: false),
        email: Field::String.with_options(searchable: true),
        password: Field::String.with_options(searchable: false),
        password_confirmation: Field::String.with_options(searchable: false),
        encrypted_password: Field::String.with_options(searchable: false),
        reset_password_token: Field::String.with_options(searchable: false),
        reset_password_sent_at: Field::DateTime.with_options(searchable: false),
        remember_created_at: Field::DateTime.with_options(searchable: false),
        first_name: Field::String.with_options(searchable: false),
        last_name: Field::String.with_options(searchable: false),
        gender: Field::Text.with_options(searchable: false),
        type: Field::String.with_options(searchable: false),
        created_at: Field::DateTime.with_options(searchable: false),
        updated_at: Field::DateTime.with_options(searchable: false),
        phone: Field::String.with_options(searchable: false),
    }.freeze

    COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES = %i[
        posts
        email
        phone
        type
    ].freeze

    SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES = %i[
        posts
        id
        email
        phone
        first_name
        last_name
        gender
        type
        created_at
        updated_at
    ].freeze

    FORM_ATTRIBUTES = %i[
        posts
        email
        phone
        first_name
        last_name
        gender
        password
        password_confirmation
        type
    ].freeze

    COLLECTION_FILTERS = {}.freeze
end
```

The view of the `new_admin_user_path` is:
[image]

Only admins can create users, but they have to type out the gender like "male" or "female" by hand. Is there a way to integrate a select menu or radio buttons that will work with administrate gem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to do this in your ATTRIBUTE_TYPES:

```
ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
  ...
  gender: Field::Select.with_options(collection: ["female", "male"]),
}
```

You might also try the AdministrateFieldEnum gem.
https://github.com/valiot/administrate-field-enum

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `gender` is your enum field of your **app/person.rb** model:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  enum gender: { female: 0, male: 1 }
  # . . .
end
```

Where your **20200922125209_create_persons.rb** migration has:

```
class CreatePersons < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :persons do |t|
      t.integer :gender
# . . .
```

In your **app/dashboards/person_dashboard.rb** add the following:

```
  ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    # . . .
    gender: Field::Select.with_options(searchable: false, collection: ->(field) { field.resource.class.send(field.attribute.to_s.pluralize).keys }),
    # . . .
  }
```

Then, just add the `gender` field to your COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES, SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES arrays.

The magic of Administrate will handle the rest, displaying "female" or "male" in the show and index views and the select dropdown in the edit form.